# Cannot read user info - Adal error cannot login

Tags: javascript, azure, reactjs, adal

I am trying to implement authentication with ADAL (Inside a react app), so I followed [the example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/blob/master/TodoSPA/App/Scripts/app.js) from Azure-Samples, and this is my code:

```
var AuthenticationContext = require('../../node_modules/adal-angular/lib/adal.js');

var adalInstance = new AuthenticationContext({
  instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
  clientId: '9897809e-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-3e6de068af92',
  postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
  endpoints: {}
});


export function enter() {
  adalInstance.login();
  var isCallback = adalInstance.isCallback(window.location.hash);
  adalInstance.handleWindowCallback();
  if (isCallback && !adalInstance.getLoginError()) {
    adalInstance.acquireToken(adalInstance.config.clientId, function (error, token) {
      if (error || !token) {
        console.log('ADAL Error Occurred: ' + error);
        return;
      }
    });
  }
  var user = adalInstance.getCachedUser();
  console.log(user);
}

export function logout() {
  adalInstance.logout();
}
```

So I have the following messages:

> ADAL Error Occurred: User login is required

and for user, I get `null`.

Currently I can go to the microsoft login page (called from the login component), login, and return to the app. I have the sessionStorage set:

```
Storage { adal.state.login: "73771340-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-858c9edcba05", adal.nonce.idtoken: "20074445-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-9f94c9b5cc31", adal.login.error: "", adal.error: "Invalid_state", adal.login.request: "http://localhost:3000/#id_token=eyJ…", adal.error.description: "Invalid_state. state: a2f210a5-e34b…", adal.token.renew.status: "Completed", length: 7 }
```

What I am doing wrong?

DATA: I am using `adal.js` library from the `adal-angular` package version: `AdalJS v1.0.13`

**EDIT**:

Now I am using an specific `adal.js` from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/master/lib/adal.js)

I changed my code to:

```
var AuthenticationContext = require('./adal.js');
```

When I compiled it (using webpack with babel for transpiling es6 code), but gave me an error about `logging is not defined`, so I added:

```
var Logging = {
  level: 3,
  log: function (message) {
    console.log(message);
  }
}
```

to the `adal` library.

And now, I am getting in the browser(firefox, *because chromes seems to not show any log I dont know why*) console:

```
Wed, 18 Jan 2017 11:52:51 GMT:1.0.13-VERBOSE: State: d3c2bb0d-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-e98a460572e2  bundle.js:74558:8
Wed, 18 Jan 2017 11:52:51 GMT:1.0.13-INFO: Returned from redirect url  bundle.js:74558:8
Wed, 18 Jan 2017 11:52:51 GMT:1.0.13-INFO: State status:false; Request type:UNKNOWN  bundle.js:74558:8
Wed, 18 Jan 2017 11:52:51 GMT:1.0.13-WARNING: User login is required  bundle.js:74558:8
ADAL Error Occurred: User login is required  bundle.js:74507:10
USER null  bundle.js:74513:4
```

Comment: adalInstance.login() will result in getting an access token, the adalInstance.acquireToken will result in getting endpoint/resource token, so I don't understand why you're passing the clientId into acquireToken.

Answer (score 2):

During integrating with PowerBi endpoint, I got a same error. After some research got this result. So the code below does auto login. Replace the method yourLogic to use the token for api request.

```js
import AuthenticationContext from "adal-angular/lib/adal";
window.AuthenticationContext = AuthenticationContext;

let authenticationContext = new window.AuthenticationContext({
        instance: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        clientId: "XXXXXXX",
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
        cacheLocation: "localStorage", // enable this for IE, as sessionStorage does not work for localhost.
    }),
    resource = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api",
    isCallback = authenticationContext.isCallback(window.location.hash);

authenticationContext.handleWindowCallback();

let user = authenticationContext.getCachedUser(),
    token = authenticationContext.getCachedToken(resource),
    loginActive = isCallback && user && !token,
    renewActive = isCallback && user && !!token;

if (user) {
    if (!renewActive) {
        authenticationContext.acquireToken(resource, (errorDesc, token, error) => {
            if (!error) {
                yourLogic(token);
            } else {
                authenticationContext.error("Error when acquiring token for resource: " + resource, error);
            }
        });
    }
} else {
    authenticationContext.login();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the characters limitation of comment, I write my troubleshooting suggestion as an answer here.

Actually, your code snippet works fine on my side. For troubleshooting and arrow down the issue, you can try the following options.

- Currently, it seems that the javascript syntax on browser is not support `export`,`require` key words. So you can check the bundled script, whether there is anything wrong about the global variables. You can test your AAD application with plain javascript within adal.js, as the sample you are referring.
- You can try to add global variable `logging` to track all the info during the authentication flow. E.G. add following code in js script.

  `Logging = {
      level: 3,
      log: function (message) {
          console.log(message);
      }
  }`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I updated my post, still not working yet